# How to hide gear button with SPFx for SPO modern UI

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions, modern-team-site

Can anyone teach me some SPFx code to hide the gear button in the upper right corner of SharePoint Online?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use SPFX extension to inject CSS to SPO, here is a demo:
https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/05/08/inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-extensions/

CSS code:

```
#O365_MainLink_Settings{
display:none
}
```

I think hiding this button is not a good choice, because we need this button to enter many SharePoint settings pages.

Comment: Keep in mind that this isn’t supported and could stop working, or break the UI, any moment. Page DOM is not an API and Microsoft can change it without any upfront notice.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a supported scenario.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/portal-branding#office-365-suite-bar